# Получить изменяющийся value="" JS

Tags: javascript

Как получить изменяющиеся значение value и передать его в другой элемент:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="test_block" value="Info">
<div id="test_block_2"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var test = document.getElementById("test_block").value;
document.getElementById("test_2").innerHTML = (test);
```

Т.е. при загрузке страницы они считывается и передается, но если я изменю значение input, то уже ничего не происходит. Нужно чтобы изменялся.

Comment: может быть стоит посмотреть в сторону *событий*,  в обработчике которого должна быть ваша логика

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: @PauloBerezini где вы тут в вопросе хоть одно событие нашли? :-) Ни разе не дубликат же...

Comment: @PavelMayorov ошибся чуть чуть

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно воспользоваться [событиями](https://learn.javascript.ru/introduction-browser-events)

```js
input.oninput = e => div.innerHTML = input.value;
```

```html
<input id='input' />
<div id='div'></div>
```